# TileMill Reference Layer Plugin doesn't work w/ non-MapBox TileJSON

Tags: tilemill

Has anyone been able to get TileMill's [reference layer plugin](https://github.com/mapbox/tilemill-reference-layer) to work w/ a TileJSON definition?

In its description, it says it can work either with a mapbox map id or a tileJSON url.  I've tried it out successfully with map ids, but when I give it a url to my tileJSON [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49790262/base_tilejson.json), nothing loads and the console outputs:

`[tilemill] Client Error: Script error.
[tilemill]     at :0
[tilemill] Client Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'a.tiles')
[tilemill]     at http://127.0.0.1:20009/assets/tilemill/js/vendor.js:5164`

Anyone had any luck with this?

**Update**: the tileJSON file must be hosted on a server that supports CORS.  That solved one problem, but still doesn't work w/ the plugin (same error output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be great if you could just add these tileJSON files anywhere like your dropbox account.  The TileMill extension expects a service to provide the file to the extension. As noted at the bottom of the link you provided, "If you have a custom tileset available elsewhere, you'll need a ***TileJSON service*** to describe this map. You can use the URL of this service for the Reference Layer field."  The MapBox id appears to be a shortcut to [their TileJSon service](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/maps/#tilejson).

Comment: Well that will do it.  Guess we'll be looking into setting up our own service.  @Greg thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in Firefox browser. On my end, apps that use a .json file are working fine in firefox while not working in Chrome.