# Self-hosting Mapbox vector tiles

Tags: vector, mapbox, mbtiles, tile-server, vector-tiles

As presented in a [talk at FOSS4G](http://vimeo.com/106228141) Mapbox Studio allows to create Mapbox vector tiles and export them as a `.mbtiles` file.

The [mapbox-gl.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl/) library can be used to dynamically style and render Mapbox vector tiles on client (browser) side.

The missing part: How can I self-host Mapbox vector tiles (`.mbtiles`) so that I can consume them with mapbox-gl.js?

I know that Mapbox Studio can upload the vector tiles to the Mapbox server and let it host the tiles. But that's no option for me, I want to host the vector tiles on my own server.

---

**The TileStream approach below turned out to be a dead end. See my answer for a working solution with Tilelive.**

---

I tried [TileStream](https://github.com/mapbox/tilestream) which can serve image tiles out of `.mbtiles` files:

My webpage uses mapbox-gl v0.4.0:

```
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.4.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.4.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
```

and it creates a mapboxgl.Map in a JavaScript script:

```
  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    center: [46.8104, 8.2452],
    zoom: 9,
    style: 'c.json'
  });
```

The `c.json` style file configures the vector tile source:

```
{
  "version": 6,
  "sprite": "https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-styles/sprites/bright",
  "glyphs": "mapbox://fontstack/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
  "constants": {
    "@land": "#808080",
    "@earth": "#805040",
    "@water": "#a0c8f0",
    "@road": "#000000"
  },
  "sources": {
    "osm_roads": {
      "type": "vector",
      "url": "tile.json"
    }
  },
  "layers": [{
    "id": "background",
    "type": "background",
    "paint": {
      "background-color": "@land"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "roads",
    "type": "line",
    "source": "osm_roads",
    "source-layer": "roads",
    "paint": {
      "line-color": "@road"
    }
  }]
}
```

... with the following TileJSON specification in `tile.json`:

```
{
  "tilejson": "2.1.0",
  "tiles": [
    "http://localhost:8888/v2/osm_roads/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
  ],
  "minzoom": 0,
  "maxzoom": 12
}
```

... which points to my TileStream server running at `localhost:8888`.
TileStream has been started with:

```
node index.js start --tiles="..\tiles"
```

... where the `..\tiles` folder contains my `osm_roads.mbtiles` file.

With this setup, I can open my webpage but only see the background layer. In the browser network trace I can see that tiles are indeed loaded when I zoom in, but the browser JavaScript error console contains several errors of the form

```
Error: Invalid UTF-8 codepoint: 160      in mapbox-gl.js:7
```

Since vector tiles are not `.png` images but rather ProtoBuf files, the tiles URL `http://localhost:8888/v2/osm_roads/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf` would actually make more sense, but that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

As pointed out by @Greg, instead of [TileStream](https://github.com/mapbox/tilestream) (my first attempt) you should use [Tilelive](https://github.com/mapbox/tilelive.js) to host your own vector tiles.

Tilelive isn't a server itself but a backend framework that deals with tiles in different formats from different sources. But it's based on [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) so you can turn it into a server in a pretty straight-forward way. To read tiles from a `.mbtiles` source as exported by Mapbox Studio, you need the [node-mbtiles](https://github.com/mapbox/node-mbtiles) tilelive module.

Side note: Current Mapbox Studio has a [bug](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-studio/issues/944) under Windows and OS X that prevents an exported `.mbtiles` file to show up at your chosen destination. Workaround: Just grab the latest `export-xxxxxxxx.mbtiles` file in `~/.mapbox-studio/cache`.

I found two server implementations ([ten20 tile server by alexbirkett](https://github.com/alexbirkett/ten20-tile-server) and [TileServer by hanchao](https://github.com/hanchao/TileServer)) who both use [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/) as a web app server.

Here is my minimalistic approach which is loosely based on these implementations:

1. Install [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)
2. Grab the node packages with `npm install @mapbox/tilelive @mapbox/mbtiles express`
3. Implement the server in the file `server.js`:

   ```js
    var express = require('express');
    var http = require('http');
    var app = express();
    var tilelive = require('tilelive');
    require('mbtiles').registerProtocols(tilelive);

    //Depending on the OS the path might need to be 'mbtiles:///' on OS X and linux
    tilelive.load('mbtiles://path/to/osm_roads.mbtiles', function(err, source) {

        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        app.set('port', 7777);

        app.use(function(req, res, next) {
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
            next();
        });

        app.get(/^\/v2\/tiles\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+).pbf$/, function(req, res){

            var z = req.params[0];
            var x = req.params[1];
            var y = req.params[2];

            console.log('get tile %d, %d, %d', z, x, y);

            source.getTile(z, x, y, function(err, tile, headers) {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(404)
                    res.send(err.message);
                    console.log(err.message);
                } else {
                  res.set(headers);
                  res.send(tile);
                }
            });
        });

        http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
            console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
        });
    });
   ```

   Note: The `Access-Control-Allow-...` headers enable cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) so webpages served from a different server may access the tiles.
4. Run it with `node server.js`
5. Set up the webpage using Mapbox GL JS in `minimal.html`:

   ```html
    <!DOCTYPE html >
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'/>
        <title>Mapbox GL JS rendering my own tiles</title>
        <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.4.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.4.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
        <style>
          body { margin:0; padding:0 }
          #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:50px; width:100%; }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id='map'>
        </div>
        <script>
          var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            center: [46.8, 8.5],
            zoom: 7,
            style: 'minimal.json'
          });
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
   ```
6. Indicate the location of the tile source and style the layers with the following `minimal.json`:

   ```json
    {
      "version": 6,
      "constants": {
        "@background": "#808080",
        "@road": "#000000"
      },
      "sources": {
        "osm_roads": {
          "type": "vector",
          "tiles": [
            "http://localhost:7777/v2/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"
          ],
          "minzoom": 0,
          "maxzoom": 12
        }
      },
      "layers": [{
        "id": "background",
        "type": "background",
        "paint": {
          "background-color": "@background"
        }
      }, {
        "id": "roads",
        "type": "line",
        "source": "osm_roads",
        "source-layer": "roads",
        "paint": {
          "line-color": "@road"
        }
      }]
    }
   ```
7. Serve the webpage and rejoice.

Comment: note that you need three `///` to define the mbtiles file in:
`tilelive.load('mbtiles://path/to/osm_roads.mbtiles', function(err, source) {`

Comment: @cdavis: That seems to depend on the operating system: Three `///` are needed for Linux and OS X like e.g. `mbtiles:///usr/local/osm_roads.mbtiles`. On Windows however only two `//` are needed if you specify the disk like e.g. `mbtiles://D/data/osm_roads.mbtiles`.

Comment: Really helpful, thanks so much, helped me serve vector mbtiles in 5'!

Comment: Hi Andreas - I couldn't get this to work - the map displays, but it is just a big blank gray square. I'm not sure where you got your mbtiles source. I've tried exporting some of the default mbtiles from tilemill.

Comment: you seem to use localhost:7777/v2/tiles/  for the location to your tiles, but where are you getting that path? Or what do you need to do to make sure the exported mbtiles file serves the images to that path?

Comment: @mheavers I used [Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio-classic/) (formerly known as `TileMill 2`) and not [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/)) to create my mbtiles file. In my example above, the `server.js` (see step 3) loads the mbtiles file using `tilelive.load('mbtiles://path/to/osm_roads.mbtiles', ...)`. The port and the url path are configured in the same file using `app.set('port', 7777);` and `app.get(/^\/v2\/tiles\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+).pbf$/, function(req, res){ ... }`.

Comment: Still no luck....though amateur....working for few days.....kept server.js, minimal.html, minimal.json and vector.mbtiles (exported from mapbox classic) by creating a folder called "vector_tiles" in my lamp localhost folder html. When trying to access minimal.html by browser 'net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED' error is showing.

Comment: Now its showing "Uncaught Error: read float" error

Comment: @AndreasBilger, I am little bit weak in Linux Solution. I am now using Wamp for developing various mapping solution with leaflet and mbtiles. It will be a great help if you answer similar question with windows solution. Basically I didn't find a way to install Tilelive, Node.js express etc on windows. So can't I install the solution on windows WAMP? Thanks

Comment: Any word on generating vector tiles ? I'm starting from scratch with a node.js script that parses a file. I know now how to serve vector tiles from any source format with tilelive, but what about making a choice concerning that format, when starting from scratch ? I don't want to pass through Mapbox Studio, I'd like to keep this local.

Comment: Tilelive seems to be no longer maintained by mapbox. any alternatives/recommendations?

Comment: If I have the .mbtiles file locally on my server can I just provide a path the file instead of the mbtiles:// protocol?

Answer (score 33):

The hosting of the vector tiles on your own is relatively straightforward. The MBTiles contains .pbf files which must be exposed to the web. That's it.

Probably easiest is to use a simple open-source server such as [TileServer-PHP](https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-php/) and put the MBTiles file to the same folder as the project files. The TileServer do all the hosting config for you (CORS, TileJSON, correct gzip headers, etc). Installation means just unpacking on a PHP enabled webserver.

If you want to start the TileServer-PHP on your laptop you can with Docker. The ready to use container is on [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/klokantech/tileserver-php/).
Under Mac OS X and Windows it runs in a couple of minutes with the Kitematic graphical user interface: https://kitematic.com/. In Kitematic just search for "tileserver-php" and start the ready to use container/virtual machine with the project inside. Then click on "Volumes" and drop into the folder your MBTiles file. You get a running hosting for your vector tiles!

Such vector tiles could be opened in the MapBox Studio as a source, or displayed with MapBox GL JS WebGL viewer.

Technically it is even possible to host the vector tiles as a plain folder on any web server or a cloud storage, or even GitHub, if you unpack the individual .pbf out of the MBtiles container with a utility like [mbutil](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil), set the CORS, TileJSON and gzip correctly. Below is a GitHub project demonstrating such an approach as well.

Try this viewer:
[image: MapBox GL JS viewer]

and see the related repos:

- https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-php
- https://github.com/klokantech/vector-tiles-sample
- https://github.com/klokantech/mapbox-gl-js-offline-example

Comment: This was by far the easiest of all the options above for me, thanks for posting.

Comment: PGRestAPI, sounds great, but failed installation for me.  I never be able to successfully install PGRestAPI. So this php tile server is my only choice and it works perfect.

Comment: This is most interesting, could you elaborate on setting CORS and TileJSON correctly for serving the pbf files? I have downloaded a pbf file from https://download.geofabrik.de/europe however the linked project contains many directories with many pbf files.

Answer (score 12):

Not to toot my own horn, but https://github.com/spatialdev/PGRestAPI is a project I've been working on that hosts .mbtiles vector tile exports from Mapbox Studio.

Still needs lots of documentation, but basically, drop your .mbtiles files into /data/pbf_mbtiles and restart the node app.  It will read thru that folder and offer endpoints for your vector tiles.

It will also look thru /data/shapefiles, and create dynamic Mapbox Vector Tiles on the fly based on your .shp.  You can also point at a PostGIS instance and get dynamic vector tiles.

We use them in conjunction with https://github.com/SpatialServer/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile, a Leaflet/Mapbox Vector Tile library we've also been working on.

Comment: PGRestAPI is no longer being actively developed unfortunately

Answer (score 10):

Thanks for the great question.  I did not know that they had finally released a stable version of the vector tiles. Moreover, you may have to work with this answer as it is a source of ideas to your "any ideas?" question.  I do not have a running studio yet.

I think one of the problems that you are running into is that you are using a tilejson file. [You need a tilejson service](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109838/tilemill-reference-layer-plugin-doesnt-work-w-non-mapbox-tilejson/110043#110043)  to use a that kind of file. Hence, I believe that you need to change your sources section to an in-line URL. Try

```
"sources": {
"osm_roads": {
  "type": "vector",
  "url": "http://localhost:8888/v2/osm_roads/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
 }
},
```

or

```
"sources": { 
"osm_orads": {
  "type": "vector",
  "tiles": [
    "http://localhost:8888/v2/osm_roads/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
  ],
  "minzoom": 0,
  "maxzoom": 12
 }
},
```

When they use `mapbox://` as the protocol, it is a alias/shorthand notation for their services.  The sources section was briefly discussed around 8:40 of the video.

One step of the new vector tile process is to curate the vector data by adjusting what you want in the data.  The other step is to bring the vector data back into MapBox Studio and render the data/create a style sheet. osm_roads would be step one while your c.json file is the style sheet. You may need a **tile live** server verses a **tile stream** as discussed around 15:01 of the video. The video says that you need additional meta data in the xml file.

The oddity here is that you reference the .pbf and style sheet elsewhere but the url that your provide is the resulting tiles .png files that are generated from the vector data.

You do not say, if you have a MapBox key.  For your own hosting, I believe that you will have to [copy the github styles and glyphs](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-styles) to your own server.  Notice again that there is a mapbox:// protocol in glyphs tag.  These two tags may not be needed because you are rendering plain lines and polygons and not POIs via icons.   It is worth taking a look.

Finally, the video says that you can take a generated vector layer back into the studio to style it.  You may want to reference your vector layer and apply your id:background and id:roads style there in the studio first.  The video says that tile live is the server behind the scene of MapBox Studio.  The idea here is to make sure that you have all the step two problems understood and fixed before you try to serve up the final vector tiles that are dynamically rendered.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Greg for your ideas. Will further investigate and come back with my findings.

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/osm2vectortiles/tileserver-gl-light is a lot easier to use than the main solutions mentioned -- no fiddling with JSON files needed. You just run it with

`tileserver-gl-light filename.mbtiles`

and then it's serving the tiles for you. It works with the predifined Mapbox GL styles such as bright-v9; after running the server you simply point whatever is consuming the tiles to

http://localhost:8080/styles/bright-v9.json

Answer (score 4):

Every answer on this page runs a server for responding to tile requests. It's easy, cheap, and fast to host vector map tiles statically on a service like AWS S3. Maybe it would be hard to do this for a planet extract, but for the west coast US, it's worked well for me so far.

This is a really good guide for setting up AWS S3 to host tiles: https://github.com/addresscloud/serverless-tiles

Once you have the tiles from Tippecanoe or OpenMapTiles, split the `.mbtiles` file into a directory with [mb-util](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil):

```
mb-util file.mbtiles tiles_folder
```

Then copy them to S3 with the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws s3 cp tiles_folder s3://bucket_name/folder_path/ --recursive --content-type application/x-protobuf
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to create vector tiles, does it?

Comment: "Once you have the tiles from Tippecanoe or OpenMapTiles". This answer describes how to use vector tiles that you've already created and saved to an `.mbtiles` file.

Comment: sure, but the question is to use vector tiles to use with  mapbox-gl.js ; does this tool create image tiles or vector tiles?

Comment: I believe you need to add `--image_format=pbf` to create pbf tiles

Comment: `mb-util` literally just does the equivalent of `for tile in tiles; do run "SELECT tile FROM tiles;" && save file to disk; done`. If you start with image tiles in your `mbtiles` file, you'll get image tiles in the output. If you start with vector tiles in the `mbtiles` file, you'll get vector output.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try out our tilehut.js server. It basically does all what you need = hosting vector tiles and comes with nice examples / docs ... and is in combination with openshift it is a 5 min setup thing. Please have a look:

https://github.com/b-g/tilehut
https://github.com/b-g/tilehut/tree/master/examples/simplemap_vector
https://github.com/b-g/tilehut#your-own-hosted-tileserver-in-5-minutes

Answer (score 3):

Super later, but now GeoServer serves pbf's (vector tile format)

Comment: Friendly advice, avoid Geoserver until you have absolutely no other way.

Answer (score 1):

Other options you can consider for tile serving;

[Tegola](https://tegola.io/) (Written in Go)

[Tiler](https://geovation.github.io/tiler)

There's a nice introduction to this topic [here](https://geovation.github.io/build-your-own-static-vector-tile-pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

See [Vector tiles on GCS](https://support.woolpert.io/hc/en-us/articles/360047530073) for a Google Cloud Platform serverless solution similar to AWS S3.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use [mbtiles-s3-server](https://github.com/uktrade/mbtiles-s3-server) (full disclosure: written by me) to serve an mbtiles file from a (versioned) S3 bucket

Taking a few bits from its README:

1. Install `pip install mbtiles-s3-server`
2. Copy the mbtiles file to another database with a high page size. Say your mbtiles file is `mytiles.mbtiles`, then create `mytiles-65536.mbtiles` with:

   ```bash
   sqlite3 my-map.mbtiles "PRAGMA page_size=65536; VACUUM INTO 'mytiles-65536.mbtiles';"
   ```
3. Upload this to S3, say to https://my-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/mytiles-65536.mbtiles
4. Start the server with the credentials of a user that has get `GetObject` and `GetObjectVersion` on this object

   ```bash
   PORT=8080 \
   MBTILES__1__URL=https://my-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/mytiles-65536.mbtiles \
   MBTILES__1__MIN_ZOOM=0 \
   MBTILES__1__MAX_ZOOM=14 \
   MBTILES__1__IDENTIFIER=mytiles \
   MBTILES__1__VERSION=1.0.0 \
   AWS_REGION=eu-west-2 \
   AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE \
   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY \
   HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN="*" \
     python -m mbtiles_s3_server
   ```

Then xyz vector tiles will then be visible at `http://localhost:8080/v1/tiles/mytiles@1.0.0/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt`.

There are also OpenMapTiler style files available that can point to this tileset (and so would only make sense if your vector tiles uses the OpenMapTile schema). For example `http://localhost:8080/v1/styles/osm-bright-gl-style@1.0.0/style.json?fonts=fonts-gl@1.0.0&tiles=mytiles@1.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [tile.stream](https://www.tile.stream) to upload my datasets and get mapbox vector tiles hosted and on demand, they've a pretty good free tier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).