# Adding a Mapbox Studio basemap to leaflet

Tags: leaflet, tiles, mapbox, json, basemap

I am using Mapbox Studio, customized a nice basemap, and downloaded it. It downloaded as a .json file with a couple thousand lines of code.

[image]

[image]

I want to be able to use this basemap (called `basemap.json`) in leaflet, like:

```
var basemap = L.tileLayer("data/basemap.json", {
maxZoom: 17,
minZoom: 9
}).addTo(map);
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions on how to load a custom Mapbox Studio basemap into leaflet?

Comment: Some more info: My goal is to make a custom basemap for use in my own project, without hosting it on MapBox's server. I basically just want custom tiles in a vector file format. Is that possible? Or do I need to make reference to my MapBox API in order to use/display the tiles?

Comment: Have you had a look at this mapbox question which has the most votes?
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125037/self-hosting-mapbox-vector-tiles

Comment: The json style is for the Mapboxgl library I think. You need to add a GL layer (use this https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-leaflet)

Comment: Thanks. I'm still tinkering with different options, so I'll post an answer once I work it out. A follow up: is it free to self-host Mapbox Studio vector tiles? That's my main interest in exploring this option. Or, does one still need to include the API that tracks page views?

Answer (score 2):

So the json file you've got contains the styles to work with mapbox.gl which isn't the same as leaflet.

Mapbox have however put together a [library](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-leaflet) to make mapboxgl stuff talk to leaflet. Documentation is pretty spare but look at the [examples](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-leaflet/tree/master/examples) and hopefully that gives you a few ideas.

Regarding self-hosting vector tiles it is certainly possible, see [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125037/self-hosting-mapbox-vector-tiles) and I've also thrown together a [github repo](https://github.com/rowanwins/mbtilesSample) which shows something similar.

Hope that helps,
Rowan