# MapBox GL JS, TileStache and Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, tilestache, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-js

Is it possible to use MapBox GL JS to render vector-tiles in a Leaflet map, without the access token?

Even if the map object itself, does not come from Leaflet directly, but it's the wrapped MapBox version, is that possible?

My question is, does my data have to reside on MapBox's server? Or it can reside on my own server, being served with TileStache, for example?

All the Mapbox examples use the accessToken, but I just want to use the webgl rendering capabilities, and serve my data, or other base layer data (osm, google, etc).

Comment: Have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125037/self-hosting-mapbox-vector-tiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Render vector-tiles in a Leaflet Map : yes, you can use this [Leaflet plugin](https://github.com/SpatialServer/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile), and point to your own tileserver in the [configuration file](https://github.com/SpatialServer/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile/blob/master/docs/configuration.md).
2. Not sure to understand what is a wrapped MapBox Version, but normally the plugin should work with any vector tile source.
3. No, your data does not have to reside on MapBox server, look at [what these amazing guys at Klokantech have done](https://github.com/klokantech/vector-tiles-sample) !

Comment: `Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile` is deprecated for Leaflet 1.0+ http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#vector-tiles