# Load vector tiles (pbf) directly from mbtiles database using OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, mbtiles, vector-tiles, osm2vectortiles

In response to the answer of Klokan Technologies in this thread: [OSM offline tiles -- mbtiles in openlayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202119/osm-offline-tiles-mbtiles-in-openlayers/222776#222776). I managed to unpack a random small mbtiles vector tile map from osm2vectortiles.org and load it locally in a browser using npm http-server, based on this OpenLayers [example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-vector-tiles.html). However I still have a question:

In the previous answer it is mentioned that the vector tiles down to zoom level 14 contains all street data with details of zoom level 20. However, when I zoom in to level 15+ I get (of course) HTTP 404 file not found errors. I can limit the zoom by setting `tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 14})` but then the map gets blurry at zoom level 15+. How can I utilize the data in zoom level 14 for higher zoom levels?

Comment: Two questions don't fit in a one question box. Suggest splitting into two questions.

Answer (score 1):

It was report to Openlayers [issues](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/6510) and closed.

Ensure that you are using Openlayers v4.2+. I was using v3.18 and faced similar issue, once upgraded to v4.3.1, resolved my issue. Follow the steps at [here](https://openmaptiles.org/docs/website/openlayers/) and don't increase the 'maxZoom' value from 14 in this code

`var tilegrid = ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({tileSize: 512, maxZoom: 14});`

Openlayers will manage with tiles of Zoom level 14 to be used at higher zoom levels.