# Artefacts using osm2vectortiles world map with OpenLayers 3 in mbtiles

Tags: openlayers, mbtiles, vector-tiles, osm2vectortiles

Using the information in this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202119/osm-offline-tiles-mbtiles-in-openlayers/222776#222776), I managed to unpack a random small mbtiles vector tile map from osm2vectortiles.org and load it locally in a browser using npm http-server, based on this OpenLayers [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avsQ2.png). 
This leaves me with this question, when I download the world map for zoom level 0-5 from osm2vectortiles.org, I seem strange triangles tiles appearing in the sea at level 2,3,4 and 5. Please see the screenshot. Land looks perfect.

How can I resolve this?

[image: water triangels]

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be caused by a bug in openlayers

https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/6341

either get a version of openlayers with that fixed or make sure your water polygon has a stroke when you set it's style. I used this to fix this issue.

```
function createMyStyle() {
    var strokedPolygon = new ol.style.Style({fill: fill, stroke: stroke});
    var styles = [];
    return function(feature, resolution) {
        var length = 0;
        var layer = feature.get('layer');
        if (layer == 'water') {
            fill.setColor('#a0c8f0');
            stroke.setColor('#a0c8f0');
            stroke.setWidth(1);
            styles[length++] = strokedPolygon;
        } .....all the other styles
        }
        styles.length = length;
        return styles;
   };
}
```