# Can I avoid the offline tile cache limit (i.e., 6k) by self-hosting a Mapbox vector tiles?

Tags: mapbox, android, cache, offline

**BACKGROUND**
I'm developing an off-line native Android mapping app. All map tiles (prefer vector, raster as fall back) must be cached locally on the device. Then the map will be overlaid with points of interest (POI), lines/shapes. The app will allow users to add their own POIs and draw lines/shapes.

**QUESTION**
I'm currently reviewing Mapbox's Android API for use as a backend tile provider, but the [6k tile limit](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/map-sdk/overview/offline/#limitations) is too small for our use. I saw [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/126550/109510) post regarding self-hosting Mapbox vector tiles and was wondering if that will allow me to bypass the tile cache ceiling limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the information given on the [Offline](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/offline/#limitations) page, its seems like you are not allowed to do this.

> Our terms of service do not allow you or an end user to redistribute offline maps downloaded from Mapbox servers.

They link to the [Pricing](https://www.mapbox.com/pricing/) page for more information, and that states in the footer the following:

> What is the limit for offline usage on mobile? Mobile apps built with
>   the Mapbox SDKs for iOS and Android can seamlessly offer offline maps
>   to users. With the Pay-as-you-go and Commercial plans, your users can
>   cache up to 6,000 map tiles on their device. Learn more on our Offline
>   help page, **or [contact us](https://www.mapbox.com/contact/sales/?page=/pricing) about Enterprise options that scale to**
>   **support your needs.**